# How to fix scales in heatmap in tableau

Tags: axes, tableau-api

I am creating a heatmap with 3X3 matrix. My x-axis scale should be 0, 0.25, 0.50 and 1. I tried a lot to fix the scale but nothing going right. Please help. How can we get the scale of 0,0.25.0.50 and 1?

Comment: Can you post an image of your heatmap - more specifically what does the x-axis scale look like at present?

Answer (score 0):

In many cases you can get an effect in Tableau by direct manipulation or drag and drop. But there are alot of other features that can be accessed via a right mouse click to get a context sensitive menu. For example, you can right click on just about anything to adjust its formatting.

For an axis, right click on the axis, select Edit axis, and you'll see a modal dialog panel that lets you set the min and max for the axis, along with the step sizes for major and minor tabs.